# What is a good word for someone who hardly ever smiles?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like whats a good adjective for someone who doesn't really smile a lot?

Comment: What about **depressed**?

Comment: Just doesn't or has reason not to or what? We looking for dour, serious, grim, or something farther afield? Cranky, grumpy, or sullen... Sober, serious, stolid, stone-faced... You have choices.

Answer (score 0):

**Unsmiling** - An unsmiling person is not smiling, and looks serious or unfriendly.  ⇒ He was unsmiling and silent. ⇒ ...the unsmiling woman in the ticket booth.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unsmiling)

Comment: 'Dour' is a Scottish word for it.

Answer (score 0):

> ***grim***:
>     [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grim):
>
>     having a very serious appearance or manner
>
> [the Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grim):
>
>     very serious and sad
>
> ***sullen***:
>     [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sullen):
>
>     used to describe an angry or unhappy person
>       who does not want to talk, smile, etc.
>
> [the Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sullen):
>
>     silent and unpleasant

And if you look up those words in a thesaurus (or even a dictionary),
you’ll find even more synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a ***straight-faced*** person.

ODO:

> **[straight-faced](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/straight-faced)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   With a blank or serious facial expression.
>   ‘Are you going to rescue me, then?’ Elaine asked, straight-faced’
>
> ‘Elwood takes the joke and tells it totally straight-faced.’